# How to I route my app to admin app in single application?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

How to route to the admin application in a single app. Which from `localhost:8080` to `localhost:8080/administration` which will open up the new application component?

I have tried to use some routing js but the drawer of the previous application still appears when I close the Admin drawer.

```
import Home2 from './App2.vue'

{
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
}, {
    path: '/admin ',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home2
}
```

I want to make it forward to the fresh new application whereas admin page. If have any suggestion please advice me.

Comment: What do you mean by new application?

Comment: It like I want to route /admin suddenly the previous app drawer still appear after I route to admin.vue so I want to make like a new section only for admin.

Answer (score 1):

it seems in the App.vue you have declared router-view and sidebars. Instead declare sidebar inside router-view children and use nested routing.